# Is it possible to connect to SVN through http?

Tags: java, svn, remote-access

I tried to checkout the Tomcat sources from:

```
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/
```

but I receive this error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
"http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/". Could not resolve host name ....
```

Is this a problem with my proxy? Is there workaround?

In a browser I can see all files.
I use SVN client TortoiseSVN 1.7.1, Build 22161 - 32 Bit , 2011/10/21 22:51:59

Comment: You should check your proxy or firewall

Comment: IMHO, It will be better to move information about your svn client from comment to question. To prevent irrelevant answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use any svn client like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

alternatively you can use svn plugin in your Eclipse IDE

[Eclipse Plugin](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)